# How to groupBy and iterate on object/array with a .reduce in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Suppose I have an array and never know what different ID's are contained. How can I group and display them dynamically? Because I will never know how many different ID's are located, I will never know how many different arrays will be created too.

Theoretically, I think we need to group all objects by these ID's and push them into new arrays. These arrays could be named as **'array-0'**, **'array-1'**, ... After that, we need to count how many arrays have been created and loop through the items by `item in array-["n in nArrays"]`. I'm sure this won't work this way because I think we can't dynamically create loops like this, but it's for a better explanation of my idea.

```js
array: [
  { id: 11, item: "item" },
  { id: 49, item: "item" },
  { id: 11, item: "item" },
  { id: 20, item: "item" },
  { id: 49, item: "item" },
  { id: 83, item: "item" },
]
```

```html
<div v-for="item in array-0">
  {{ item }} // all items with id 11 e.g.
</div>

<div v-for="item in array-1">
  {{ item }} // all items with id 20 e.g.
</div>
```

But it should be dynamic

```html
<div v-for="item in array-[n in nArrays]">
  {{ item }}
</div>
```

Comment: It's important to master all the array methods: `filter`, `map`, `find`, `reduce`, `splice` etc... I recommend that you take Wes Bos's JS30 free challenge course to practice those: https://javascript30.com/ (can only make the array cardio ones) or any other challenges foundable on Codewars or alike. This free one is also quite good as a starter: https://javascript.info/array-methods

Comment: Thank you kissu! I will take it to heart, because I realize that I need to work more and more often with such methods... :-)

Comment: Yeah, a big chunk of frontend is how to *massage* the data to make it fit our needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [this reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#grouping_objects_by_a_property) with the following function

```js
function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
  return objectArray.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    const key = obj[property];
    const curGroup = acc[key] ?? [];

    return { ...acc, [key]: [...curGroup, obj] };
  }, {});
}
```

This would give us this well formatted object to then [iterate on](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for-with-an-object)

```js
const t = [
  { id: 11, item: "first one" },
  { id: 49, item: "tasty thing" },
  { id: 11, item: "amazing right?" },
  { id: 20, item: "cool cool" },
  { id: 49, item: "love watermelons" },
  { id: 83, item: "and you?" },
]

groupBy(t, 'id')
// this will give us the following
{
  "11": [
    {
      "id": 11,
      "item": "first one"
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "item": "amazing right?"
    }
  ],
  "20": [
    {
      "id": 20,
      "item": "cool cool"
    }
  ],
  "49": [
    {
      "id": 49,
      "item": "tasty thing"
    },
    {
      "id": 49,
      "item": "love watermelons"
    }
  ],
  "83": [
    {
      "id": 83,
      "item": "and you?"
    }
  ]
}
```

The whole could would look like this

```html
<template>
  <main>
    <div v-for="(groupedArray, id) in objectToLoopOn" :key="id">
      <pre v-for="array in groupedArray" :key="array.item">{{ array }}</pre>
      <hr />
    </div>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
const groupBy = (objectArray, property) => {
  return objectArray.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    const key = obj[property];
    const curGroup = acc[key] ?? [];

    return { ...acc, [key]: [...curGroup, obj] };
  }, {});
};

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      objectToLoopOn: groupBy(
        [
          { id: 11, item: "first one" },
          { id: 49, item: "tasty thing" },
          { id: 11, item: "amazing right?" },
          { id: 20, item: "cool cool" },
          { id: 49, item: "love watermelons" },
          { id: 83, item: "and you?" },
        ],
        "id"
      ),
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Providing us this kind of visual result

[image]